# Error: HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Spring_Test threw exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying a simple Spring-MVC application which takes input from user and display it on screen. I am getting following error message:

Exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Spring_Test threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Root Cause:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/Spring_Test-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/Spring_Test-servlet.xml]
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:467)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:483)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:358)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:325)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am sharing content of my files:

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>Spring_Test</display-name>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Spring_Test</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Spring_Test</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.leader" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
 </beans>
```

Can you please help me to come out of this issue?

Comment: Are there more stacktraces?

Comment: Rename spring-servlet.xml to /WEB-INF/Spring_Test-servlet.xml

Comment: @Jens : Hi... I added root cause along with exception clause. Both of them are complete.

Comment: @farrellmr HI... I renamed it and now I ma getting error:   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/Spring_Test-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'viewClass' is required

Comment: Yes I wondered why that wasnt there - it would be something like this - <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things needing fixed -

- Rename spring-servlet.xml to Spring_Test-servlet.xml
- Add view resolver to the directory holding your view files -

> ```
> <bean id="viewResolver"
>  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"> 
>  <property name="viewClass"
>  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />  <property
>  name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />  <property name="suffix"
>  value=".jsp" />  </bean>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like either you have annotation on your controller or that is not being loaded correctly.

Also, dont u need spring mvc entries in your spring config xml.
Something like:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
```

Here is a post explaning the steps http://www.journaldev.com/2433/spring-mvc-tutorial-for-beginners-with-spring-tool-suite

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue but my code included `headers="Accept=application/json"` at request mapping and it worked fine when I removed that tag.